# Hot to make position: absolute subnav ul slideable

Tags: jquery, position, slidetoggle, absolute

How can I make a 2 level horizontal navigation slideable?
Mainmenu (level 1: L1) is a floated unsorted list.
Submenu (level 2: L2) is also a floated unsorted list with absolute position.
On slideToggle the submenu (L2) is not affected because its position is absolute. Did anybody know a workaround for this problem?

```
<ul class="L1">
  <li class="active dropdown">
    <a href="#">Menu1.1</a>
    <span class="L2_outer">
        <ul class="L2" style="display:block;">
          <li><a href="#">Sub1.1</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Sub1.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub1.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </span>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu1.2</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">Menu1.3</a>
    <span class="L2_outer">
        <ul class="L2" style="display:none;">
          <li><a href="#">Sub2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </span>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu1.4</a></li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/opaque/Lvwjj2sx